# event.preventDefault() и form.submit() в обработчике события submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой код, он работает, но смущает возможность бесконечного цикла

```
orderForm.on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //some code here
    this.submit();
})
```

Почему не происходит бесконечный цикл, правильно ли всё в этом коде?

Как выглядит пример правильного кода в таких ситуациях?

Answer (score 2):

Метод [HTMLFormElement.submit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) не генерирует событие submit из расчета на то, что программист осознанно напрямую отсылает форму. Поэтому такая конструкция не зацикливается

Использовать блокировку стандартной отправки формы и отправлять её вручную методом submit можно, например, при наличии своих валидаций на поля:

```js
$("#orderForm").on("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var $orderError = $("#orderError");
  $orderError.text("");
  var _this = this;
  validate($("#orderValue").val(), function(isValid) {
    if (isValid) {
      _this.submit();
    }
    else {
      $orderError.text("Incorrect order value");
    }
  });
});

function validate(value, onResult) {
  //асинхронная валидация
  setTimeout(function() {
    onResult(value.length >= 3);
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form id="orderForm" action="test">
  <input id="orderValue" />
  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
  <div id="orderError" class="error"></div>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: +1, но: пример выглядит притянутым за уши ), так как вместо `this.submit();` можно было вызывать `event.preventDefault();` по условию. Я использую `form.submit();`, когда в обработчике `$().submit` присутствует асинхронность, а сам обработчик обязан отработать до того, как будет известен результат проверки условия отправки формы.

Comment: @Igor согласен, синхронный вариант выглядит неубедительно. Попытался переделать на асинхронный вариант так, чтобы не переусложнять пример. У нас на работе `<form>` тегов вообще почти нет, так что сам я привык данные "форм" Ajax-запросом отсылать